# Ошибка про попытке установки зависимости behat в phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Пытаюсь добавить в проект зависимость behat в phpstorm но возникает ошибка (в php первый раз так что прошу не пинать но по работе срочно понадобилось) помогите решить тралу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вечер добрый, сам пока behat не юзаю, но погуглив нашел пару интересных ссылок, не знаю можно ли считать ссылки за ответ, поэтому оставлю в комментах, посмотрите: 
[здесь](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/07/using-behat-in-phpstorm/), [здесь](https://vivait.co.uk/labs/running-behat-in-phpstorm-eap-through-vagrant) и [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkANbpGalJU)

Comment: Да там черным по белым написано установи ssl расширение для php

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было установить openssl. завелось